# Combining queries in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have multiple queries regarding screening results for a study that list, by month and year, the number of patients consented, the number of patients consented that have Medicare, and the number of patients consented that came from certain hospitals. I cannot figure out how to have, within a single query, the month, date, and aggregate totals from each condition in individual columns. My end goal is the following:

| Year | Month | # Consented | # Medicare | # From Select Hospitals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 01 | 10 | 3 | 4 |
| 2021 | 02 | 12 | 6 | 1 |

Etc.

I tried to write a UNION query in SQL combining the three individual working queries, but that returned a "Your query does not include the specified expression 'Year([dtmApproach])' as part of an aggregate function." My code from attempting to add a new aggregate column to an existing, working query is below.

I feel like there's a stupidly simple fix for this but I can't figure it out. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
'Count consented patients query
SELECT Year([dtmApproach]) AS [Year], Month([dtmApproach]) AS [Month], Count(tblScreening.intMMID) AS CountOfintMMID
FROM tblScreening
WHERE (((tblScreening.intCode)=1 Or (tblScreening.intCode)=2))
'Merge with consented and on Medicare query
UNION SELECT Year([dtmApproach]) AS [Year], Month([dtmApproach]) AS [Month], Count(tblScreening.intMMID) AS CountOfintMMID
FROM tblScreening
WHERE (((tblScreening.intCode)=1 Or (tblScreening.intCode)=2) AND ((tblScreening.intPayer)=2))
GROUP BY  Year([dtmApproach]), Month([dtmApproach]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GROUP BY clause is missing from the first SELECT. You cannot apply GROUP BY to the UNIONed query. Apply it to both SELECTs:

```sql
SELECT
    Year([dtmApproach]) AS [Year],
    Month([dtmApproach]) AS [Month],
    Count(tblScreening.intMMID) AS CountOfintMMID
FROM
    tblScreening
WHERE
    (((tblScreening.intCode)=1 Or (tblScreening.intCode)=2))
GROUP BY
    Year([dtmApproach]), Month([dtmApproach])
UNION
SELECT
    Year([dtmApproach]) AS [Year],
    Month([dtmApproach]) AS [Month],
    Count(tblScreening.intMMID) AS CountOfintMMID
FROM
    tblScreening
WHERE
    (((tblScreening.intCode)=1 Or (tblScreening.intCode)=2) AND
    ((tblScreening.intPayer)=2))
GROUP BY
    Year([dtmApproach]), Month([dtmApproach]);
```

But since both SELECTS are based on the same table and the same columns, I would use the `IIf` function to sum the different types:

```sql
SELECT
    Year([dtmApproach]) AS [Year],
    Month([dtmApproach]) AS [Month],
    SUM(IIf(condition1, 1, 0)) As NumConsented,
    SUM(IIf(condition2, 1, 0)) As NumMedicare,
    SUM(IIf(condition3, 1, 0)) As NumFromSelectedHospitals
FROM
    tblScreening
GROUP BY
    Year([dtmApproach]),
    Month([dtmApproach])
```

But I am not sure what the conditions would be, as you have not explained how you are selecting the 3 types of patients.

Comment: IIF function worked like a charm, much appreciated and I'll remember this going forward.